# How to install Canon PIXMA iP1600?

Tags: 11.04, printing, canon

I have a Canon iP1600 connected wireless through Win system laptop, I just can't install the printer although I've googled and tried various ways recommended. I'm at my wit's end!

Answer (score 3):

1. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Connect the printer to the computer--but *don't start it!*--and run  these commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libpng3
   sudo apt-get install alien
   sudo apt-get install libxml2
   ```
3. Now download the driver for your printer and install it with these commands:

   ```
   cd ~
   wget http://files.canon-europe.com/files/soft24301/software/24301.tgz
   tar -xvf 24301.tgz
   mkdir iP2200_Linux_260
   mv iP2200_Linux_260.tar.gz iP2200_Linux_260
   cd iP2200_Linux_260
   tar -xzf iP2200_Linux_260.tar.gz
   sudo alien --to-deb --scripts *i386.rpm
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```
4. Now:

   ```
   cd /usr/lib
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng.so.3 libpng.so.3
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4 libtiff.so.3
   sudo ln -s libxml2.so.2 libxml.so.1
   sudo ldconfig
   ```
5. Now you have to change the file /usr/share/cups/model/canonip2200.ppd. So you have to run this command in terminal:

   ```
   sudo gedit /usr/share/cups/model/canonip2200.ppd
   ```

   Add these lines at the end:

   ```
   *OpenUI *CNQuality/Quality: PickOne
   *DefaultCNQuality: 3
   *CNQuality 2/High: "2"
   *CNQuality 3/Normal: "3"
   *CNQuality 4/Standard: "4"
   *CNQuality 5/Economy: "5"
   *CloseUI: *CNQuality
   ```
6. Now in the same file (still `/usr/share/cups/model/canonip2200.ppd`) in the text editor, find these lines:

   ```
   *OpenUI *Resolution/Output Resolution: PickOne
   *DefaultResolution: 600
   *Resolution 600/600 dpi: "<</HWResolution[600 600]>>setpagedevice"
   *CloseUI: *Resolution
   ```

   Delete them, and replace them with these lines:

   ```
   *OpenUI *Resolution/Output Resolution: PickOne
   *DefaultResolution: 600
   *Resolution 600/600 dpi: "<</HWResolution[600 600]>>setpagedevice"
   *Resolution 1200/1200 dpi: "<</HWResolution[1200 1200]>>setpagedevice"
   *Resolution 2400/2400 dpi: "<</HWResolution[2400 2400]>>setpagedevice"
   *Resolution 4800/4800 dpi: "<</HWResolution[4800 4800]>>setpagedevice"
   *CloseUI: *Resolution
   ```
7. Now you have to restart the cups deamon with this command in terminal:

   ```
   sudo service cups restart
   ```
8. Turn on the printer.
9. As the printer starts up, the system will automatically search for driver. Select *Canon* for manufacturer and select *iP2200 Ver.2.60* for the printer model. If the procedure for automatically search the driver don't start, open the dash (for open the dash click the windows key on the keyboard) and search for printer.

Comment: I've installed 12.04 beta yesterday. Followed your instructions and printer works a treat. This is the first time I've ever managed to get the ip1600 to work with Ubuntu

Comment: It worked fine for a .386, but how can I do it for a 64bit computer (with 64bit ubuntu)?

Comment: There is better solution for newest ubuntu's: http://askubuntu.com/questions/240338/how-to-setup-canon-inkjet-pixma-ip-1300