# Canon pixma iP1600 stopped working when upgrading to 11.10

Tags: printing, canon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Canon PIXMA iP1600?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41615/how-to-install-canon-pixma-ip1600)
>   [Canon Pixma IP1600 won't print](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77743/canon-pixma-ip1600-wont-print)

I had my canon pixma iP1600 printer working well in Ubuntu 11.04 (I followed what was wrote [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41615/how-to-install-canon-pixma-ip1600) to accomplish that).

Then I upgraded my Ubuntu to version 11.10 but the upgrade went wrong and I was forced to reinstall Ubuntu 11.10 from scratch. After that, I tried to install my printer just as I did before but I was not able to print with success anymore.

I reinstalled Ubuntu 11.10 a second time, this time without encrypting my home folder and I was able to print successfully. To take any doubts I reinstalled Ubuntu 11.10 a third time and again I could not print anything.

So, can someone help me to put my printer working in Ubuntu 11.10 with my home folder encrypted?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to be something with permissions. Can someone figure this out?

Comment: I still can't print... Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you try the instructions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/82337/how-do-i-get-a-canon-mg-mp-and-mx-series-usb-printer-working) and see if they help? The encrypted home is not likely to be causing this.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41615/how-to-install-canon-pixma-ip1600