# How do I get a Canon Pixma MG 3150 working?

Tags: 11.10, printing, canon, pixma

I've got the new Canon Pixma MG 3150 and so far, I can't seem to find a driver anywhere. I do have the CD for both Windows and Mac, but this doesn't help me, as I have Ubuntu 11.10. I'd prefer to have it running on the wifi.

I'm really new to this, so I need for you to explain this to me as basically as possible.

Comment: Go to the power cog ( upper right hand corner) and click on printing. Click add. Click network printer. Does the printer show up?

Comment: Can you try this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/82337/how-do-i-get-a-canon-mg-mp-and-mx-series-usb-printer-working

Answer (score 2):

http://support-sg.canon-asia.com/contents/SG/EN/0100393702.html

try with this one! You have deb file inside. Just choos correct one and simply install

Answer (score 1):

On canon site search for i.e.  cnijfilter-mg5300series-3.60-1-deb  (I have a MG 5350 printer, wifi only attached now on ubuntu 11.10) or i.e.:  -  canon your(series)type debian

Downloadded it, extracted to desktop

see files, right click the one ending on .sh

open in terminal

execute in terminal

it does its thing, now my printer works for both text and photo printing, by wifi.