# Canon Multifunctional MG3150 - printer OK, but scanning is NOT

Tags: printing, canon, scanning

Any ideas where the driver can be found or how to activate the scanner driver if it is hidden in the printer driver?

Comment: See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/83863/how-do-i-get-a-canon-pixma-mg-3150-working) or [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/82337/how-do-i-get-a-canon-mg-mp-and-mx-series-usb-printer-working) duplicate question for how to get everything working. Once you do, your only way to scan will be from GIMP. Open it, open 'File/Create/ScanGearMP' and scan. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

try this [MG3100 series IJ Printer Driver Ver. 3.60 for Linux](http://support-sg.canon-asia.com/contents/SG/EN/0100393702.html) 
its a deb package

hope it helps.