# Scanner not working for Cannon Image Class MF4412

Tags: 11.10, drivers, scanner

I recently switched from windows vista to ubuntu 11.10.
I realized that my   printer/Scanner/photocopier was not working.I went on www.canon-asia.com and downloaded the driver for the printer.Now the printer is working fine.But the site doesnt have a driver for the scanner for linux and Xsane is not detecting my scanner . I tried running the windows and mac version of the driver through wine and acetoneiso but to no avail.
Please help me out . I really need my scanner to work

Thanks

Comment: You scan through GIMP only for Canon multifunction machines, see my comment at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/123638/canon-multifunctional-mg3150-printer-ok-but-scanning-is-not#comment147662_123638) for links to more info.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got my scanner to work .
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?goto=newpost&t=1427330
Although the model mentioned in this post was different from mine.still the scanner worked!! :)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this site to solve the problem
-  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1427330

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.