# USB Printer Canon Pixma MP550 installed, recognized, but does nothing

Tags: printing, canon, pixma

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install a Canon Printer MP190 driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-printer-mp190-driver)

core i7, 64bit, ubuntu11.10 : all new, also me, have parallel Win7 and run
befor suse11. Plug USB, printer Canon Pixma MP550 recognised, suitable gutenprint installed, free for all on the server. Tried other drivers, because *icc not found, still no print out!

Seems, that the driver is in a loop, don´t understand the errors really.
Installed ia32-libs for debian i386 driver, wrong architecture first, with sudo
installed, crash by plugging the printer. 
now gutenprint again, printer starts cleaning, then nothing more. Scan is working
fine.

May be it is this:

```
 cupsdReadClient: 21 Closing because Keep-Alive disabled
```

but don´t know, how to change. Perhaps also misunderstanding between en-driver
and german printerhardware. Or:Cannot disable printing from internet.
What can i do?

Also i am missing Yast or Hardwaremanager, is there something same?

Comment: Have a look at this post and try installing 'Canon cnijfilter' from the Ubuntu software center: http://askubuntu.com/questions/82337/how-do-i-get-a-canon-mg-mp-and-mx-series-usb-printer-working

Comment: Did installing that package resolve the problem ?

Comment: How can I install a Canon driver?

linkeditflag
 
answered Dec 29 '11 at 0:04
fossfreedom♦
40.9k44377
 
 
Many thanks fossfreedom, now it is working. Only at 3. not the model but cnijfilter-mp550series! Also still in cups the button search for usable printers does find nothing, it is there under the button printer adjustable. – Marek Dec 29 '11 at 13:08   That link helped, the gutenprint has had bugs and must removed first! I copied from my question, but the link is not active, hope you can do this for me.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to convey with that comment. Can you please update your question ? there is also this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-printer-mp190-driver

Comment: That is the link mentioned above. But first the installed gutenprint-driver must be removed.