# Is there a way to get a driver for a Canon pixma mg5320 printer?

Tags: printing, canon

I tried to use the driver from a an earlier mg series printer but it does not work, and so far have not found a way to get it to. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you confirm you've tried the mg5200 series driver from this PPA?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-driver

Comment: Tried looking for it in the Software center yet? Search 'Canon cnijfilter' more detail here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/82337/how-do-i-get-a-canon-mg-mp-and-mx-series-usb-printer-working

Answer (score 2):

In fact, there are mg5300-series drivers available from Canon. They are not (yet) on their European site, but you can find them on 
http://support-asia.canon-asia.com

I have a mg5350 with wifi. I downloaded the mg5300 series driver (.deb version) and installed it without any problem in Kubuntu 11.10.

Alex

Comment: The installer script failed om my Maverick 64bit, but I found a workaround, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/124275/installation-of-drivers-for-canon-mp5300-series-fails/124284#124284

Answer (score 1):

I have an MG5300 and 12.04.  I just configured the MG5300 to use my wifi network, using standard instructions.  Then I added a Printer in Ubuntu, and selected Network Printer.  It found the MG5300 and when I selected to add it, it automatically searched for the appropriate driver (over net, I assume), found it, installed it, and I was able to print a test page.  Printing over wifi works well, and the driver seems to support all usual MG5300 settings.  I've not been able to get scanning to work over wifi though.

Comment: what network protocol did you use?  / what is the uri?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a commercial driver called Turboprint. I recall the best print quality with this driver for Canon printers.

http://www.turboprint.info/