# Installation of drivers for Canon MG5300 series fails…

Tags: wireless, printing, canon

I have a new MG5320 printer, and several ubuntu computers on my local network.

I am trying to install drivers to get them to work.

The  `ppa:michael-gruz/canon` does not (yet) have drivers for the MG5300 series.

The Canon linux drivers from [support-asia.canon-asia.com](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/P/search?model=PIXMA%20MG5370&menu=download&filter=0&tagname=g_os&g_os=Linux) provides drivers and an install script.

The install script fails on my amd64 10.10 with the error "An error occurred. The package management system cannot be identified."  A glance at the install script shows testing for dpkg…

```
  dpkg --version 1> /dev/null 2>&1
  c_system_deb=$?
```

returns `0` for `c_system_deb`

And then tests and exits at…

```
    if [ $c_system_rpm = 0 -a $c_system_deb = 0 ] || [ $c_system_rpm != 0 -a $c_system_deb != 0 ]; then
        return $C_ERR_CODE
```

Yet I know dpkg is installed, *i.e.*

```
  ⋯@⋯:~/Desktop/cnijfilter-mg5300series-3.60-1-deb$ sudo dpkg --version
  Debian `dpkg' package management program version 1.15.8.4ubuntu1 (amd64).
  This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
  later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
```

How do I install thei printer using the LAN with wireless AP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this "[manual](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/P/search?model=PIXMA+MG5370&filter=0&menu=manual)" which gave rudimentry steps for installing not using the "script".

This is how I pulled it off…

Downloaded the driver from [here](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/P/search?model=PIXMA+MG5370&filter=0&menu=download).

Uncompressed the folder `cnijfilter-mg5300series-3.60-1-deb` to my Desktop.

From the folder `Packages` installed the packages `cnijfilter-common_3.60-1_amd64.deb` and `cnijfilter-mg5300series_3.60-1_amd64.deb` in that order.  This was for the 64bit Ubuntu, the other two in the folder are for the 32 bit Ubuntu.

**UPDATE**: To find the MAC address: [a]use the wobble pointer (around the OK button) up to where it shows setup. [b] Press the function button under "setup" [c] wobble pointer left to "Device Settings" [d]Select "LAN settings" [e] select "Confirm LAN settings" [f] select WLAN setting list [g] wobble button down to MAC address.

Opened a terminal and ran these commands (where XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX is the MAC address of the printer.

```
sudo service cups restart
/usr/sbin/lpadmin -p MG5300LAN -m canonmg5300.ppd -v cnijnet:/XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -E
/usr/sbin/lpadmin -d MG5300LAN
```

At this point the rudimentary steps ended, and I relied on the last hope of the ignorant, stumbling around ⋯ and it worked.

Opened from the Ubuntu main menu `System>Administration>Printing`

Selected the printer `MG5300LAN` and from the `Printing` window menu bar `Selected Printer>Properties`.

On the Setting sub·page that opened, to the right of "Device URI:" text box containing the MAC address *et al*, pressed the button named `Change…`

On the popup window "Change Device URI" I selected `Network Printer` and then `Find Network Printer`

After waiting a bit, `Canon MG5300(MG5320LAN…)(Current)` showed up.  Selected and applied.

Back on `Printer Properties…` popup·window, pressed button `Print Test Page`.  Waited for test page, breathing huge sigh of relief.

Note: This is the very first time I have installed a printer on Linux, heretofore using printers attached to a Windows system.

Comment: Hmm...your driver  link takes me to a search page, and the only driver I can find now provides an RPM. Any ideas?