# Canon MG5300 series won't do duplex printing in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing, canon, duplex-printing

I upgraded an 11.10 32 Ubuntu to 12.04, and it has drivers that support the Canon MP5300 series (mine is a MG5320).

The MG5320 will print duplex (two sides of one page), but not with the drivers that came with 12.04.

Is there a way to get it to print in duplex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canon provides drivers that print duplex on the MG5300 series on Asian servers.

Their recommended installation method failed but another way is available.

How to do it is detailed at in another [questions answer.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124275/installation-of-drivers-for-canon-mp5300-series-fails/124284#124284)