# How can I configure a Canon Pixma MG5300 to print wirelessly?

Tags: 12.04, networking, printing, canon

How can I configure a printer to print wirelessly in ubuntu 12.04 ?

I have a canon pixma mg 5300 series, and I am able to print correctly by usb (the drivers were installed). Now I'm trying to do it wirelessly.

I configured the printer so that it connects to my access point, and assigned it a static IP (192.168.0.6). It connects correctly, and responds to ping. Now I would like to use ubuntu 12.04 to send a file to be printed to that printer. I went to the dash and opened the application named 'printing'. From there I clicked 'add'. Then 'network printer', then 'find a printer' (though here, I also tried a couple of the other possibilities that are mentionned, none worked). I typed the IP address. I clicked 'find', nothing happened. I can't go forwards.

So how to make this wireless configuration work?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124275/installation-of-drivers-for-canon-mg5300-series-fails

Comment: No it's not related. My question is mainly about the wireless issue, rather than the printer itself.

Comment: I've added a MX860 via the http uri, and it seems to add fine, and the test page spools, but it causes the printer to crash (screen goes black) and nothing is printed.