# How do I get a Canon PIXMA MX350 printer working?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, printing, ppa, canon

Is anybody successfully addressing a Canon PIXMA MX printer (MX350 in my case) on current Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit)?

Comment: Related question [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/82337). Can you try [this link](http://support-hk.canon-asia.com/P/search?model=PIXMA+MX357&menu=download&filter=0&tagname=g_os&g_os=Linux), download, extract and open the two 64-bit Debian packages (the bottom two)? I do this for a different but similar model and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed comment, although I'm only seeing files with "i386" in their name. I'll try when I'm again testing 12.04 (me-tv is still an issue for me)

Comment: You're right. I have a MG5350 and 64-bit drivers exist. I would send Canon an email requesting drivers or help. I did, and they replied quickly told me what to do. I was shocked they actually replied AND had Linux support.

Comment: No luck in my case, but this answer seems promising: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140799/canon-mx870-printer-only-shows-processing-on-the-status-lcd

Comment: Using ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk (trunk!) I had to purge and install the drivers after upgrading to 12.04 from 11.10.

Comment: Also gutenprint seems to work though achieving slightly better results with the other driver (which still works after upgrading to 12.10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk` and install `cnijfilter-mx350series`.

Adjusting `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/michael-gruz-canon-trunk-quantal.list` to read

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu quantal main
```

also makes the driver install in 12.10.

Answer (score 3):

Go to this website
http://software.canon-europe.com/products/0010699.asp.

Select Linux, press submit and select : "Printer Driver for Debian Linux (3.1)".
Its name should be cnijfilter-mx860series-3.10-1-i386-deb.tar.gz

This driver also works for MX320 and MX330 printers so maybe also for MX350.

Untar it and do

```
cd cnijfilter-mx860series-3.10-1-i386-deb/packages
sudo apt-get install libpopt-dev # not sure it is useful
sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i cnijfilter-common_3.10-1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i cnijfilter-mx860series_3.10-1_i386.deb
```

Now just go to System Settings/Printing. Press Add, and you should see your printer if you wait a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow this except for the mx870: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1488850

Answer (score 0):

I made a tutorial where I describe the installation of canon pixma mx715 in linux ubuntu (scanner + printer):

http://blog.milsystems.de/2013/01/canon-pixma-mx715-unter-linux-ubuntu-installieren/

I think it also helps you with your mx350, because it's the same way only other driver data (you can translate the site to English with the flag-icon on the right side of the blog)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.