# Canon MX870 printer only shows "Processing" on the status LCD

Tags: 12.04, printing, canon

I had my Canon MX870 installed perfectly fine in 11.10, but since upgrading to 12.04, it no longer works. The printer is recognized in print settings and when I attempt to print a test page, the printer LCD displays a "Processing" message, but then it disappears and nothing happens. Here are my logs (note that printing did not succeed despite the access logs showing success):

```
# /var/log/cups/access_log

localhost - - [22/May/2012:12:29:35 -0400] "POST /printers/Canon-MX870 HTTP/1.1" 200 412 Print-Job successful-ok
```

-

```
# /var/log/cups/error_log

W [22/May/2012:12:25:51 -0400] failed to CreateProfile: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'Canon-MX870-Gray..' already exists
W [22/May/2012:12:25:51 -0400] failed to CreateProfile: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'Canon-MX870-RGB..' already exists
W [22/May/2012:12:25:51 -0400] failed to CreateDevice: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:device id 'cups-Canon-MX870' already exists
W [22/May/2012:12:25:51 -0400] failed to CreateProfile: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'Canon-MX870-Gray..' already exists
W [22/May/2012:12:25:51 -0400] failed to CreateProfile: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'Canon-MX870-RGB..' already exists
W [22/May/2012:12:25:51 -0400] failed to CreateDevice: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:device id 'cups-Canon-MX870' already exists
W [22/May/2012:12:25:51 -0400] failed to CreateProfile: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'Canon-MX870-Gray..' already exists
W [22/May/2012:12:25:51 -0400] failed to CreateProfile: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'Canon-MX870-RGB..' already exists
W [22/May/2012:12:25:51 -0400] failed to CreateDevice: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:device id 'cups-Canon-MX870' already exists
W [22/May/2012:12:25:51 -0400] failed to CreateProfile: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'Canon-MX870-Gray..' already exists
W [22/May/2012:12:25:51 -0400] failed to CreateProfile: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'Canon-MX870-RGB..' already exists
W [22/May/2012:12:25:51 -0400] failed to CreateDevice: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:device id 'cups-Canon-MX870' already exists
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution:
I originally had the printer working under 11.10 with the michael gruz ppa, but this no longer worked in 12.04 and attempting to install from Ubuntu's Printing manager didn't work either.

I found a michael gruz ppa that has been updated for 12.04:
https://code.launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon-trunk/+packages

I first removed the old driver with Synaptic Package Manager, then added the new one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mx870series
```

After doing this, installing the printer with the Printing manager worked.

Comment: This is valid only for i386. On my 64-bit system, the canon-trunk repository gives a lot of errors.

Comment: I'm on a 64 bit system and it's still working for me error free.

Comment: I can confirm that it works like a charm on my 12.04 x64.

Answer (score 0):

It does work. Thank you.
I use your method and follow the description: (`/tmp/LinuxDrivers/Canon_Printer/cnijfilter-source-3.10/ppd`)
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1488850

```
kimiko@kimiko-Lenovo-G770:~$ uname -a
Linux kimiko-Lenovo-G770 3.2.0-24-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 21 16:52:17 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```