# How to remove the old driver for Canon MX870 and install a new one?

Tags: printing, canon

I am using 12.04. In addition to [Canon MX870 printer only shows "Processing" on the status LCD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140799/canon-mx870-printer-only-shows-processing-on-the-status-lcd), I'm not sure if I successfully removed the old MX870 driver (I removed it by using Ubuntu Software Center), then I added a new PPA, `apt-get update` and then:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk 
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mx870series
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package cnijfilter-mx870series is not available, but is referred to by another package.   
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted,  or is only available from another source
E: Package 'cnijfilter-mx870series' has no installation candidate
```

How could I resolve this?

EDIT: It seems to me like a PPA issue:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
$ sudo apt-cache policy ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
N: Unable to locate package ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk

/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ **find . -name "*michael*"
./michael-gruz-canon-trunk-precise.list
./michael-gruz-canon-trunk-precise.list.save
$ grep -lr mx870
```

No results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did I do to resolve this issue is the following:

I removed my MX870 from Ubuntu (Printing).
Since I couldn't install cnijfilter-mx870series, I just completely removed repository entries by michael-gruz.

> $ sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:michael-gruz/canon
>
> $ sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
>
> $ cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
>
> $ sudo find . -name "michael-gruz*"
>
> $ sudo rm -rf michael-gruz*

I restarted Ubuntu and manually added my Canon PIXMA MX870 (via Printing), since the driver is already included in Ubuntu 12.04.

I'm still confused what happened with the PPA issue I've mentioned in my question (I've contacted the PPA maintainer), but who cares, since now it works without his drivers!