# Canon MX 892 printer on USB recognized not working

Tags: printing, canon

On Ubuntu 12.04, trying to install a Canon PIXMA MX892 printer, connected by USB cable. Ubuntu now recognizes printer (as Canon MX880 series FAX), but printing test page goes nowhere except endless "processing - rendering completed".

Comment: Have a look at [this similar question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/82337/how-do-i-get-a-canon-mg-mp-and-mx-series-usb-printer-working?rq=1), or try downloading the drivers from the Canon website in Alex Bixel's answer below.

Answer (score -1):

Try going on [Canon's site](http://support-hk.canon-asia.com/) and manually installing the correct driver for your printer. It may be that Ubuntu has the wrong driver or none at all (though in the latter case I don't think it would recognize it).