# How do I install my new Canon MG5250 printer? (MG5200 series)

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I just bought a Canon MG5250 multifunction printer because I thought that it would work well with Ubuntu, but it's hard to get it to work.

How do I install this printer?

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/q/82337/12864)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install a Canon printer or scanner driver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-printer-or-scanner-driver)

Comment: For any Canon printer see this answer (also works for Ubuntu 20.04):
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261887/canon-g1010-driver-installation-on-ubuntu-20-04/1294113#1294113

Answer (score 10):

I googled and found the instructions included below.  The instructions worked:  I now have a **fully working printer with color and duplex!** For B&W printing, [follow Dahzler's answer.](https://askubuntu.com/a/174741/5786)

*Unresolved:*

- How to [get **scanning** to work!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171314/how-make-scanner-function-of-canon-mg5250-work) (I will put a link here to a solution when I figure it out! There seems to be at least one intimidating [method for experts](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11983928&postcount=27).)

  - The scanner seems to be recognized by Canon's `scangearmp` but not by Ubuntu's built-in simple scanner app that I much prefer. See further details in the scanner question linked above.

**Instructions:**
The below is copied from http://linuxdeal.com/Printer-PIXMA-MG5220 but I have adapted it slightly to be easier to follow.

---

OS: Xubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal
Date: Jul 25th, 2011
Recommended

```
          Printer  Scanner  
USB       Perfect  Untested  
Wireless  Perfect  Perfect
```

Driver instructions:

1. Download the driver files to Downloads folder:
   Printer: http://support-my.canon-asia.com/contents/MY/EN/0100301702.html
   Scanner: http://support-my.canon-asia.com/contents/MY/EN/0100303002.html
2. Unpack the tar.gz files by right clicking on them and selecting 'unpack here'
3. Install the **printer** .deb packages by going into the folder and double clicking on the right .deb file for your system

   - 32-bit:
     `cnijfilter-common_3.40-1_i386.deb`
     `cnijfilter-mg5200series_3.40-1_i386.deb`
   - 64-bit:
     `cnijfilter-common_3.40-1_amd64.deb`
     `cnijfilter-mg5200series_3.40-1_amd64.deb`
   - Go to Application Menu > Printing > and search for a MG5200 printer if it has not been automatically added by now.
4. Install the **scanner** .deb packages in the same way as the printer installers above:

   - 32-bit:
     `scangearmp-common_1.60-1_i386.deb`
     `scangearmp-mg5200series_1.60-1_i386.deb`
   - 64-bit:
     `scangearmp-common_1.60-1_amd64.deb`
     `scangearmp-mg5200series_1.60-1_amd64.deb`
   - If dpkg does not work then go into a command line and use the `cd` tool to change directory into the path were your unpacked files are, look for the install.sh file:
   - `sudo sh install.sh`

   Enjoy! :)
5. Comments

I ran a test print that printed a test page with Grayscale, Red, Green, Blue, Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, and Black colors with an ubuntu header.

Comment: This solution is outdated, for community's sake. :) Recent Ubuntu versions can install from a huge list of network printers almost automatically. See Bernhards answer below. The scanner should work using SANE.

Answer (score 6):

Under newer Ubuntu versions (checked with 13.10 and later), just install the cups-backend-bjnp package to use your Canon Pixma MG520 via network. The Printer settings dialog will then find it when you tell it to add a new printer, and offer a Gutenprint driver to set it up.

Comment: Verified for Linux Mint 17.1, should work for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS As Well

Comment: confirmed for Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and MG5240

Answer (score 4):

To print in grayscale only, duplicate your original printer and rename the new one something like "MG5250-Black-and-White".  Then, in the Properties->"Job Options"->"Other Options (Advanced"), add the option "CNGrayscale" and change the value to "true".

Then, when you want to print B&W (greyscale), just choose that printer instead.  I set it as my default printer since B&W is what I print mostly.

Comment: There's a setting `print-color-mode`=`color` that I can set to `monochrome` instead, but when I click "Apply" it just reverts back to `color`. Your suggestion to actually _add_ a new setting worked! I now have a true greyscale printer, as well as a color printer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There's even a PPA you can use, it is as simple as this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-common
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mg5200series
```

Answer (score 2):

The name of the PPA has changed. I've used this on Precise and Saucy.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-common
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a Canon MG5250. I had downloaded the `.deb` files from Canon's site but these installed driver version 3.4 which gave me limited functionality (e.g. only supported 600dpi).  Having followed a mix of advice on this page (thank you!) I now have driver version 3.9 which supports up to 2400dpi amongst other features.  Here's what I entered into a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-common
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mg5200series
```

I tried it without the last line and only got driver version 3.4.

Scanner -  following the above has got the scanner to work, but only using Canon's utility (not Simple Scan) and only on wirelessly connected devices (my net-book).  It doesn't work on my desktop PC which the printer is connected to (USB).

Answer (score 2):

I got this printer working on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial (and it should also work for Vivid).

Unfortunately, there is no Xenial driver for the **Canon Pixma MG5200** series (I have an **MG5220**). However, Michael Gruz's Utopic package works fine. Therefore, after adding his repo, you need to manually update it to point to the utopic repository. Here is how:

```
sudo bash
add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
sed -i 's/xenial/utopic/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/michael-gruz-ubuntu-canon-trunk-xenial.list
apt-get update
apt-get install cnijfilter-mg5200series-64
```

(That installs the 64 bit version. There's also a `...-32` version available.)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I think that still many users may be interested in this:

It's possible to make the Canon PIXMA MG5250 working with SimpleScan and others via SANE.
The solution is to [add the device to the PIXMA SANE service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/200915/how-to-map-network-scanner).

1. Add your PIXMA device to `/etc/sane.d/pixma.conf`

   ```
   bjnp://<device_ip_address>
   ```
2. To enable SANE, change the respective line in `/etc/default/saned` to

   ```
   `RUN=yes`
   ```

   **Update**: Most recent versions of SANE start automatically. Check if this configuration entry is really necessary in your setup beforehand. Thanks to [w-sky](https://askubuntu.com/users/65362/w-sky) for the hint.
3. Start SANE.

   ```
   sudo service saned start
   ```
4. Use the SANE-based scanning tool you like. Both SimpleScan and XSANE are working for me.

Comment: Most recent versions of SANE will start automatically and /etc/default/saned should not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I don't have much to provide in way of an answer other than to deal with ScanGearMP because SANE can't easily be configured for a dynamic IP address. This is the conclusion I've come to.

My CUPS configuration, which was configured using Canon's Asian MX470 series driver, works flawlessly by utilizing the cnijbe:// protocol. However, I still cannot figure out how to configure SANE with the device serial number as opposed to a dynamic IP which changes each time I cycle the power on my printer.

I have followed the advice of everyone here and elsewhere in configuring SANE, starting the backend, editing pixma.conf to (in vain) see if the cnijbe:// protocol would work.

Here is my CUPS URI: cnijbe://Canon/?port=net&serial=##-##-##-##-##-##
(I replaced my serial number with number signs in the example above)
I can print without issue, yet my scanner will only be recognized by ScangearMP.

To clarify, I am using MX-15 (Based on Debian 8.2) and SANE is simply INSANE because it simply won't find my scanner.