# Network scanner (Canon) stops after upgrade from 15.04 to 15.10

Tags: 15.04, canon, scanner, 15.10, xsane

I have just upgraded Kubuntu 15.04 to 15.10 - all very nice. The machine is working well, and I can print to the Canon pixma mx420 with no problems as before, but both Skanlite and xsane return errors. xsane returns:

```
Failed to open device 'pixma:MX420_192.168.1.5': Invalid argument.
```

Also:

```
scanimage -L
device `pixma:MX420_192.168.1.5' is a CANON Canon PIXMA MX420 multi-function peripheral
```

So the system is finding the scanner at the correct network address, but I don't know how to debug further. Note this all worked well before upgrade on this machine and the scanner has been tested from another laptop on the same network successfully - which is still on Kubuntu 15.04.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a slight update - I have also tried to use xscanimage from the command line and I get the same message as with xsane - I would guess that this is very much the same interfacing. My guess as a newbie is that the backend sane library is no longer talking to any of the frontend tools. This must be specific to my setup as I would think this would be spotted in alpha / beta testing ;-)

Comment: More information:
upgraded kubuntu 15.10 : 
$ scanimage -L
device `pixma:MX420_192.168.1.5` ....

working laptop kubuntu 15.04:
$ scanimage -L
device `pixma:MX420_5FFED4000000` ....

So, working is using printer name and 15.10 upgrade is using ipv4 - maybe a clue ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bug in a few versions of sane-backends (pkg libsane) which affects versions 0.17.10 - 0.17.18 (the last one actually present in 15.10). Since the bug has been fixed since July 2015 we just need it packaged in a debian/ubuntu repo. Until then there are several possible workarounds:

- Get a version of libsane, libsane-common and libphoto2-pack10 from vivid and downgrade. Vivid contains 0.17.4 and thus is not affected.
- Get a version of libsane, libsane-common and libjpeg62-turbo from [debian experimental](https://packages.debian.org/experimental/libsane). I found the version 0.17.23 in it and it seems to work for me. But be carefull, its experimental :-).
- Build the sane-backends libraries by youself. Not a straightway method, you better get the debian packaging patch to get it into proper paths.
- Use ScanGearMP which apparently works anyway. Is suitable for simple scanning for example through GIMP.

Comment: OK, sane-pixma v.0.17.18 does not work, v.0.17.4 does - downgrading packages libsane and libsane-common to vivid versions helped (and the libgphoto2-port10 as a dependency). Currently looking for a suspicious commit in libsane GIT.

Comment: Update: sane-pixma works since v.0.17.19 again (a version just after the one in wily). However I didn't find the newer version in a package anywhere.

Comment: OK all working. I downloaded the 3 packages (**libjpeg62-turbo_1.4.80-115-gfb907b2-1_amd64.deb, libsane_1.0.25+git20150927-1_amd64.deb, libsane-common_1.0.25+git20150927-1_all.deb**) from debian experimental and installed them using sudo gpkg -i filename. Great answer - Many thanks Honkir

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar problem with the Canon Pixma MG5450 (MG5400 series) using Ubuntu 15.10.

## Problem:

Using "Simple Scan" to scan a document failed with:

> Failed to scan
>   Unable to connect to scanner

But the device was properly discovered using `scanimage -L`

```
$ scanimage -L
$ device `pixma:MG5400_C5BFDC000000' is a CANON Canon PIXMA MG5400 Series multi-function peripheral
```

## Solution:

Download 3 packages from [Debian Expirimental - Libs](https://packages.debian.org/experimental/libs/)

- **libjpeg62-turbo**

  - Version: 1:1.4.80-115-gfb907b2-1
- **libsane-common**

  - Version: 1.0.26~git20151121-1
- **libsane**

  - Version: 1.0.26~git20151121-1

(My reputation won't allow me to add more then 2 links. Otherwise i would have linked those libraries.)

**Install *deb packages**

```
# #Install the downloaded packages as root
# dpkg -i libjpeg62-turbo_1.4.80-115-gfb907b2-1_amd64.deb
# dpkg -i libsane-common_1.0.26~git20151121-1_all.deb
# dpkg -i libsane_1.0.26~git20151121-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: This answer is the most complete! It helped me with my Ubuntu 15.10 upgraded from 15.04 and issue with detecting scanner in Canon PIXMA MX870. Same issue has been resolved with the proposed fix. Well done, thank you!

Comment: BTW, there could be a possible issue with TeamViewer's dependency, since it relies on libjpeg62 library.

Comment: After reinstalling TeamViewer 11, Ubuntu removed Simple Scan and Xsane and offered me to REMOVE the following packages:
  argyll argyll-ref gnome-control-center-data gnome-settings-daemon
  libcolord-gtk1 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 xsane-common

Comment: I posted a new question caused by following those steps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/739592/issue-related-with-unmet-dependencies-after-installing-new-libraries

Comment: Unfortunately libsane-common is no longer available in Debian Experimental. Any other relatively sane source?

Comment: These packages didn't work for me but http://askubuntu.com/a/798622/20924 did.

Comment: There are dependency problems with Ubuntu 16.04 and libsane_1.0.27 experimental refused to install, but the --auto-defonfigure option helped at the end. Now I'm scanning too. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem with the Canon Pixma MG5350 (MG5300 series) using Ubuntu 15.10. Installing the  Debian Expirimental - Libs works.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to debug this a little further - but still no solution.

If I do the following:

```
export SANE_DEBUG_PIXMA=255
scanimage -T
```

The output from scanimage is as follows:

```
[sanei_debug] Setting debug level of dll to 0.
[sanei_debug] Setting debug level of pixma to 255.
[pixma] pixma is compiled with pthread support.
[pixma] pixma version 0.17.18
[pixma] Scanner model MP150(Canon PIXMA MP150) not found, giving up! MX420 series
[pixma] Scanner model MP170(Canon PIXMA MP170) not found, giving up! MX420 series
[pixma] Scanner model MP450(Canon PIXMA MP450) not found, giving up! MX420 series
[pixma] Scanner model MP500(Canon PIXMA MP500) not found, giving up! MX420 series
```

... Cut lots of scanners

```
[pixma] Scanner model MX410(Canon PIXMA MX410) not found, giving up! MX420 series
[pixma] Scanner model found: Name MX420(Canon PIXMA MX420) matches MX420 series
[pixma] pixma_collect_devices() found Canon PIXMA MX420 at bjnp://192.168.1.5:8612
[pixma] pixma_find_scanners() found 1 devices
[pixma] Scanner model MP150(Canon PIXMA MP150) not found, giving up! MX420 series
[pixma] Scanner model MP170(Canon PIXMA MP170) not found, giving up! MX420 series
[pixma] Scanner model MP450(Canon PIXMA MP450) not found, giving up! MX420 series
[pixma] Scanner model MP500(Canon PIXMA MP500) not found, giving up! MX420 series
```

... Cut lots of scanners

```
[pixma] Scanner model MX360(Canon PIXMA MX360) not found, giving up! MX420 series
[pixma] Scanner model MX410(Canon PIXMA MX410) not found, giving up! MX420 series
[pixma] Scanner model found: Name MX420(Canon PIXMA MX420) matches MX420 series
[pixma] pixma_collect_devices() found Canon PIXMA MX420 at bjnp://192.168.1.5:8612
[pixma] pixma_open(): Canon PIXMA MX420
[pixma] pixma_connect() failed EINVAL
[pixma] pixma_open() failed EINVAL
[pixma] pixma_close(): Canon PIXMA MX420
scanimage: open of device pixma:MX420_192.168.1.5 failed: Invalid argument
```

I found the EINVAL message interesting.

Comment: Lastly from scamimage -T on a working 15.04 machine:  

`[pixma] pixma_collect_devices() found Canon PIXMA MX420 at bjnp://5FFED4000000.local:8612  

[pixma] pixma_open(): Canon PIXMA MX420  
[pixma] Reader task started  
[pixma] Reader task id=140278759941888 (threaded)  
scanimage: scanning image of size 638x877 pixels at 24 bits/pixel  
scanimage: acquiring RGB frame, 8 bits/sample  
scanimage: reading one scanline, 1914 bytes... [pixma]  
[pixma] pixma_scan(): start  
[pixma]   line_size=1914 image_size=1678578 channels=3 depth=8`
---

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issues with Ubuntu 16.04 and Canon MG5350 and thanks to the info in here I answered a similar question [at this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788151/ubuntu-16-04-simple-scan-i-o-error/836112#836112) - which updates slightly the previous references and packages.

The essential parts are: Download these 3 packages libsane-common_1.0.26~git20151121-1_all.deb libsane_1.0.26~git20151121-1_amd64.deb libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.1-1_amd64.deb. If you need a location for the packages look at the link provided. Then install each package as root, i.e `sudo dpkg -i package-name` I have tested it with simple-scan, xsane, and scangearmp and all works fine.