# Network PIXMA MX925 on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, canon, scanner

Following these steps from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688642/network-scanner-canon-stops-after-upgrade-from-15-04-to-15-10), I've managed to discover my scanner over the network with `scanimage -L` but I'm still getting an error with `scanimage -T`:

```
[sanei_debug] Setting debug level of pixma to 5.
[pixma] pixma is compiled with pthread support.
[pixma] pixma version 0.17.24
[pixma] Scanner model found: Name MX920(Canon PIXMA MX920 Series) matches MX920 series
[pixma] pixma_collect_devices() found Canon PIXMA MX920 Series at bjnp://10.0.0.5:8612
[pixma] pixma_find_scanners() found 1 devices
[pixma] Scanner model found: Name MX920(Canon PIXMA MX920 Series) matches MX920 series
[pixma] pixma_collect_devices() found Canon PIXMA MX920 Series at bjnp://10.0.0.5:8612
[pixma] pixma_open(): Canon PIXMA MX920 Series
[pixma] *mp150_open***** This is a generation 4 scanner.  *****
[pixma] Reader task started
[pixma] Reader task id=139912999573248 (threaded)
scanimage: scanning image of size 638x877 pixels at 24 bits/pixel
scanimage: acquiring RGB frame, 8 bits/sample
scanimage: reading one scanline, 1914 bytes...  [bjnp] bjnp_open_tcp: ERROR - Can not connect to scanner: Connection refused
[pixma] Reader task terminated: EINVAL
[pixma] read_image():reader task closed the pipe:0 bytes received, 1678578 bytes expected
FAIL Error: Invalid argument
[pixma] pixma_close(): Canon PIXMA MX920 Series

[bjnp] bjnp_open_tcp: ERROR - Can not connect to scanner: Connection refused
```

Same with the firewall desactivated or sudo

```
$ dpkg -l | grep sane
ii  libsane:amd64                                               1.0.26~git20151121-1                       amd64        API library for scanners
ii  libsane-common                                              1.0.26~git20151121-1                       all          API library for scanners -- documentation and support files
ii  libsane-hpaio                                               3.15.7-0ubuntu4                            amd64        HP SANE backend for multi-function peripherals
ii  sane                                                        1.0.14-11                                  amd64        scanner graphical frontends
ii  sane-utils                                                  1.0.26~git20151121-1                       amd64        API library for scanners -- utilities
rc  xsane                                                       0.998-6ubuntu1                             amd64        featureful graphical frontend for SANE (Scanner Access Now Easy)
ii  xsane-common                                                0.998-6ubuntu1                             all          featureful graphical frontend for SANE (Scanner Access Now Easy)
```

`uname` gives:

```
Linux 4.2.0-27-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

One more precision, I have two others Laptop on Kubuntu 14.04 32bits and 64bits. The 32bits works and the 64bits don't.

### UPDATE 1 : Update libsane with the git ppa

```
ii  libsane:amd64                                               1.0.26-git20160214-wily0                   amd64        API library for scanners
ii  libsane-common                                              1.0.26-git20160214-wily0                   amd64        API library for scanners -- documentation and support files
ii  libsane-hpaio                                               3.15.7-0ubuntu4                            amd64        HP SANE backend for multi-function peripherals
ii  sane                                                        1.0.14-11                                  amd64        scanner graphical frontends
ii  sane-utils                                                  1.0.26-git20160214-wily0                   amd64        API library for scanners -- utilities
rc  xsane                                                       0.998-6ubuntu1                             amd64        featureful graphical frontend for SANE (Scanner Access Now Easy)
ii  xsane-common                                                0.998-6ubuntu1                             all          featureful graphical frontend for SANE (Scanner Access Now Easy)
```

Still the same error. scangear is working of course because it's not using libsane but I want to use the Java librairie jfreesane.

### UPDATE 2 : Last maj of the git ppa is working

A standard MAJ of the system made thaht the librairies work as usual.

Thanks for your help/time

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider installing the [daily SANE ppa](https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git).  That gained 90% functionality of our Canon multipurpose device.  The only thing that isn't functional is the sheet feeder, and that works with Canon's bare-bones `scangearmp2`.  Can you find that latter program for your scanner?

Comment: This solved my trouble, but there is a disclaimer:
  «17. Sep 2016: The PPA cannot compile SANE's sources anymore. 1.0.26-git20160712 is the last running package.»

Comment: I am sorry to hear that!  Thanks for the information. I am glad it helped you.