# Issue related with unmet dependencies after installing new libraries

Tags: package-management, dependencies, scanner

After upgrading from Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10, I had an issue with my scanner on Canon PIXMA MX870 that was not recognized by Simple Scan or Xsane. I've found my answer on how to make it work:

[Original issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688642/network-scanner-canon-stops-after-upgrade-from-15-04-to-15-10)

The proposed solution suggested to install experimental libraries on my Ubuntu 15.10. It really resolved my issue and I could see my scanner, but unfortunately TeamViewer 11 required libjpeg62 (the original library). After I reinstalled TeamViewer, it "fixed" some of the libraries it needed, but then my Simple Scan and Xsane apps are gone.

Output from my "apt-get autoremove;apt-get autoclean":

> The following packages will be REMOVED:
>   argyll argyll-ref gnome-control-center-data 
>   gnome-settings-daemon   libcolord-gtk1 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 
>   xsane-common

[Debian Expirimental - Libs](https://packages.debian.org/experimental/libs/)

- **libjpeg62-turbo**
  Version: 1:1.4.80-115-gfb907b2-1
- **libsane-common** 
  Version: 1.0.26~git20151121-1
- **libsane**
  Version: 1.0.26~git20151121-1

When I try to install Simple Scan, the following error appears:

> simple-scan: Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4 is
>   to be installed

Similar message appears when trying to install Xsane:

> xsane: Depends: xsane-common (= 0.998-6ubuntu1) but 0.998-6ubuntu1 is
>   to be installed
>
> ```
>    Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.21-0ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
>    Depends: libgimp2.0 (>= 2.4.0) but 2.8.14-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
>    Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0) but 2.46.1-1 is to be installed
>    Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.14.0) but 2.24.28-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
>    Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but 8c-2ubuntu8 is to be installed
>    Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but 1.2.51-0ubuntu3.15.10.2 is to be installed
>    Depends: libsane (>= 1.0.11-3) but 1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
>    Depends: libtiff5 (>= 4.0.3) but 4.0.3-12.3ubuntu2 is to be installed
>    Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
> ```

QUESTIONS:

1. Is it possible to make my TeamViewer work as well as Simple Scan and
   Xsane?
2. How could I fix the issue with my libraries?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a way in order to answer my own questions:

**1)** It appears I can't have both - experimental and buggy stable version of those libraries. So I had to choose. I can live without Simple Scan and Xsane, since scangearmp still works with my scanner! The solution is to get rid of the experimental libs.

**2)** Again, the solution is to get rid of the experimental libs, by following:

> # #Re-install the downloaded packages as root

- # dpkg -i libjpeg62-turbo_1.4.80-115-gfb907b2-1_amd64.deb
- # dpkg -i libsane-common_1.0.26~git20151121-1_all.deb
- # dpkg -i libsane_1.0.26~git20151121-1_amd64.deb

> # #Now remove the experimental libraries completely

- # dpkg -P libsane
- # dpkg -P libsane-common
- # dpkg -P libjpeg62-turbo

Start "Ubuntu Software Center" and let Ubuntu do the repair of missing libraries, by clicking Ok. Alternatively, you may install and uninstall Simple Scan, or Xsane and we're done - all libraries are now fixed, and everything's back to normal!