# sane stopped working after update to 16.04

Tags: canon, scanner, sane

I've been using my Canon I-Sensys 8280 scanner wireless for a couple months and it worked fine, when I updated to 16.04 LTS it suddenly stopped working.  It seems to be detected scanimage -L reports a couple of problems but ends up detecting my scanner

```
*[bjnp] udp_command: ERROR - no data received (timeout = 1000*)
*[bjnp] bjnp_init_device_structure: Cannot read mac address, skipping this scanner*

*[bjnp] udp_command: ERROR - no data received (timeout = 1000)*

*[bjnp] add_scanner: ERROR - Cannot read scanner make & model: bjnp://192.168.0.103*
*device `pixma:MF8200C_192.168.0.103' is a CANON Canon i-SENSYS MF8200C Series multi-function peripheral*
```

When I try to load the preview or to scan I get an I/O error message

```
*[bjnp] sanei_bjnp_write_bulk: ERROR - Scanner length of write confirmation = 0x0 bytes = 0, expected 4!!*

*[bjnp] sanei_bjnp_write_bulk: ERROR - Scanner length of write confirmation = 0x0 bytes = 0, expected 4!!*

*[bjnp] udp_command: ERROR - no data received (timeout = 500)*
```

I've updated the backends (scanimage (sane-backends) 1.0.26git; backend version 1.0.26)

Any idea what might be the problem and how to fix it? I'm pretty upset that it just stopped working, would not have upgraded if I had known since I have to use the scanner everyday, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the fact there is no xenial version for this PPA is part of the problem  (https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon) anyone has an idea where I could get cnijfilter-common (the latest edition possible) for 16.04LTS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After applying these updates, it is now working properly

libsane (1.0.26-git20160710-xenial0, 1.0.26-git20160711-xenial0)

libsane-common (1.0.26-git20160710-xenial0, 1.0.26-git20160711-xenial0)

sane-utils (1.0.26-git20160710-xenial0, 1.0.26-git20160711-xenial0)

Comment: Where did you get these packages? I cannot find these exact versions anywhere.

Comment: I think I've just found it at https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git - works like a charm!