# Ubuntu 16.04: simple-scan I/O error

Tags: scanner

While attempting to scan with simple-scan, I very often (but not always!) get an I/O error telling me that the scanner is unreachable. I don't think it's a physical connection issue (cable or USB port problem), because printing with the same device works without problems.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.4. and my device is Samsung SCX-3205W. I have installed the newest drivers from the producer website.

Here is the console output of simple-scan:

```
$ simple-scan -d
[+0,00s] DEBUG: simple-scan.vala:674: Starting Simple Scan 3.20.0, PID=3395
[+0,00s] DEBUG: Connecting to session manager
[+0,08s] DEBUG: ui.vala:2032: Loading state from /home/ja/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+0,08s] DEBUG: ui.vala:1995: Restoring window to 600x400 pixels
[+0,08s] DEBUG: autosave-manager.vala:64: Loading autosave information
[+0,08s] DEBUG: autosave-manager.vala:259: Waiting to autosave...
[+0,08s] CRITICAL: gtk_event_controller_reset: assertion 'GTK_IS_EVENT_CONTROLLER (controller)' failed
[+0,15s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1447: sane_init () -> SANE_STATUS_GOOD
[+0,15s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1453: SANE version 1.0.25
[+0,15s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1514: Requesting redetection of scan devices
[+0,15s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:803: Processing request
[+0,19s] DEBUG: autosave-manager.vala:281: Autosaving book information
[+0,28s] DEBUG: ui.vala:2124: Saving state to /home/ja/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+2,23s] DEBUG: ui.vala:2124: Saving state to /home/ja/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+7,51s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:338: sane_get_devices () -> SANE_STATUS_GOOD
[+7,51s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:350: Device: name="smfp:usb;04e8;3441;Z5E6BFEB501435J" vendor="Samsung" model="SCX-3200 Series on USB" type="Scanner"
[+10,86s] DEBUG: ui.vala:2124: Saving state to /home/ja/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+15,60s] DEBUG: ui.vala:2124: Saving state to /home/ja/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+15,76s] DEBUG: ui.vala:2124: Saving state to /home/ja/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+16,50s] DEBUG: simple-scan.vala:404: Requesting scan at 300 dpi from device 'smfp:usb;04e8;3441;Z5E6BFEB501435J'
[+16,50s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1560: Scanner.scan ("smfp:usb;04e8;3441;Z5E6BFEB501435J", dpi=300, scan_mode=ScanMode.COLOR, depth=8, type=ScanType.SINGLE, paper_width=0, paper_height=0, brightness=0, contrast=0)
[+16,50s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:803: Processing request
[+16,53s] DEBUG: ui.vala:2124: Saving state to /home/ja/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+16,68s] DEBUG: ui.vala:2124: Saving state to /home/ja/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+19,40s] DEBUG: ui.vala:2124: Saving state to /home/ja/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+50,73s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:864: sane_open ("smfp:usb;04e8;3441;Z5E6BFEB501435J") -> SANE_STATUS_IO_ERROR
[+50,73s] WARNING: scanner.vala:868: Unable to get open device: Error during device I/O
[+51,10s] DEBUG: ui.vala:2124: Saving state to /home/ja/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+115,09s] DEBUG: ui.vala:2124: Saving state to /home/ja/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+116,12s] DEBUG: ui.vala:2124: Saving state to /home/ja/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+117,44s] DEBUG: autosave-manager.vala:195: Deleting autosave records
[+117,44s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1587: Stopping scan thread
[+117,44s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:803: Processing request
[+117,44s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1598: sane_exit ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing this, these 3 packages need to be downloaded and installed.

```
libsane-common_1.0.26~git20151121-1_all.deb
libsane_1.0.26~git20151121-1_amd64.deb
libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.1-1_amd64.deb
```

The first two packages can be found in the Debian experimental libs at this link
https://packages.debian.org/experimental/libs/

The last package I found in this link
https://packages.debian.org/sid/libjpeg62-turbo

In some cases you may need to navigate to an ftp mirror site to actually download.
Once downloaded, simply install each package as root i.e
`sudo dpkg -i package`

I have tested with simple-scan, xsane, and scangearmp and all works fine.

Comment: I'm new here - so sorry if you feel I have been snarky.  Thank you for editing my post to make it so more readeable - I'll get the hang of this perhaps.  I can't explain why *package* was not printed in italic as I requested thus following the standard convention that the user would have to type the downloaded package in lieu of the word *package*

Comment: The wording in your comment came off that way, but all is good.  I'm going to do some comments cleanup to make sure we don't clutter comments here :)  (Also, Italics don't work in code formatting, which is fine)

Comment: Because of dependency problems with all other sane 1.0.25 packages on Ubuntu 16.04, libsane_1.0.27 experimental refused to install. But the --auto-defonfigure option helped at the end. Now I'm scanning too. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
install libsane-common_1.0.26~git20151121-1_all
install libsane_1.0.26~git20151121-1_amd64
install libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.1-1_amd64

Loaded repository 
http://ftp.ports.debian.org/debian-ports/
synaptic only comes up with 1.0.27-1 experimental2
for sane-common. No libsane option.
Unable to find the link
https://packages.debian.org/sid/libjpeg62-turbo
```

Added the source url and synaptic showed

```
The repository may no longer be available or could not be contacted because of network problems. If available an older version of the failed index will be used. Otherwise the repository will be ignored. Check your network connection and ensure the repository address in the preferences is correct.
```

Had to remove repositories and re-install libsane libsane-common sane and simple-scan