# Scanner Not Found On Wireless Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, scanner, epson

I was able to get the printer epson workforce wf-3520 to print wirelessly, but it can not find the scanner. Does anyone know the steps to get Ubuntu 14.04LTS to find the wireless scanner? It only works when plugged into the USB. I know it has something to do with sane.

Comment: Read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/200915/how-to-map-network-scanner) answer. Although it refers to a Canon model, the method described is make/model agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a scanner driver and add the scanner IP address.

Go to [Epson drivers site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule) and search for your scanner.

Download the scanner driver and network plugin.

```
iscan_2.30.1-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_amd64.deb
iscan-data_1.36.0-1_all.deb
iscan-network-nt_1.1.1-1_amd64.deb
```

These packages are for 64-bit Ubuntu. If you have a 32-bit installation, then download 1st and 3rd packages with i386 in the name.

Copy these files to your Home folder and run in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i iscan*.deb
```

Then find IP address of your scanner and add it to `/etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf` as e.g.

```
 net 192.168.1.101
```

You will be able to scan with Simple Scan, xsane, iscan or other software.

Comment: Good answer, 2018 after download instead of running dpkg directly you need to: cd Download folder;     tar xaf iscan-bundle-1.0.4.x64.deb.tar.gz;
   cd iscan-bundle-1.0.4.x64.deb;
   ./install.sh