# How can I use a Canon network scanner(MF4870dn) in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: networking, drivers, canon, scanner

It is my first time to upload a question in this community. I don't know about much on the linux system or network, so it maybe a silly question for experts. Sorry about that in advance.

My situation is as follows: I am now running Ubuntu 16.04 as an operating system of my laptop. And my office has a scanner(actually, it is a multifunction printer/scanner "imageCLASS MF4870dn") made by Canon. The scanner has an IP address in the form of xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. I would like to use the scanner as a network scanner using the IP address. But it fails.

I refered to the following pages.

1. [How to map network scanner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/200915/how-to-map-network-scanner)

I expected that this is a right solution for me. Especially, I thought that the "backendname" for the scanner is also "pixma". I followed the first answer there, almost in the same way.
But I faced the error message when I typed "service saned start".
The error message was "Failed to start saned.service: Unit saned.service is masked".

2. https://kbpdfstudio.qoppa.com/how-to-solve-failed-to-start-saned-service-unit-saned-service-is-masked-on-linux/

So I googled the error message and I could find the solution there. I followed the solution, and sane seems to be active when I typed "sudo systemctl status saned.socket". But the same error message comes again even after I reboot my laptop.

I also read the manual for sane https://help.ubuntu.com/community/sane
but it was not very helpful for my problem.
How can I resolve this problem and use the network scanner?

Comment: "Unit saned.service is masked"  so did you unmask it ;-) (`sudo systemctl start saned.socket && sudo systemctl enable saned.socket && sudo systemctl status saned.socket` last part should show it is no longer masked.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thank you for your answer! Actually, I typed in the exact same commands which is in the second link (also same commands as you suggested). But same error occurs.
Actually, I could not understand the term "mask". Can you explain to me what it means?