# Failed to restart saned.service: Unit saned.service is masked

Tags: networking, wireless, scanner, canon

I try to install canon pixma scanner on WIFI to my ubuntu 16.04. I have followed the tutorial: put `RUN=yes` in */etc/default/saned*
and changed  */etc/sane.d/saned.conf* with unchecked 192.168.0.1/24.
I even: `sudo adduser saned lp`
and: `sudo adduser $USER saned`
and: `sudo -s`
`su -s /bin/bash saned`
also I add: `sudo systemctl start saned.socket`
and: `sudo systemctl enable saned.socket`

When I do: `sudo service saned restart`
I get 
`"Failed to restart saned.service: Unit saned.service is masked"`

No way to connect my scanner (Canon Pixma MG5750) to ubuntu!
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/281027/66509

Comment: I even added "sudo systemctl unmask saned" it did'nt work

Comment: did u fix it by any chance??