# Adding network scanner

Tags: networking, kubuntu, scanner

SO my lab has a printer+scanner Canon MF8300C series. I have successfully add it as printer but failed to add it as scanner. Is there any way to setup this? I am really blind about setting network printer. I am using Kubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to enter the ip address to connect to it on a web page, then it can detect which OS you have. And if you are lucky, on the web page it can suggest which driver you should install to use that functionality.

If that doesn't work then this might point you to a solution.
[How to map network scanner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/200915/how-to-map-network-scanner?rq=1)