# Canon Pixma IP1600 won't print

Tags: 11.10, printing, canon, pixma

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Canon PIXMA iP1600?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41615/how-to-install-canon-pixma-ip1600)

So I'm new to ubuntu and I'm trying to install/config my Canon pixma ip1600 printer in 11.10. I've went through the install that comes up when you connect your printer and selected ip1600 tried both drivers listed I also have done this steps.

I'm trying to switch from windows but if i cant print then I'm not going to bother doing so. any help is thanked. ps printer light flashes when I say print but nothing happens.

- [How to install Canon PIXMA iP1600?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41615/how-to-install-canon-pixma-ip1600)

Answer (score -2):

You may have a long battle on your hands!

My Pixma iP1500 sort of worked in Ubuntu 11.04 (black ok but colour washed out yet ok in windows), but then stopped as soon as 11.10 was launched. There are many postings regarding this problem and although it's been blamed on CUPS and the Ubuntu Kernel, I'm finding that five months later and all the updates and fixes I can find my printer remains dead while Ubuntu happily tells me it's printed.

I keep Windows XP on my computer for printing, and have had to use it more and more as the Ubuntu programmes I need don't quite work. I'm finding Windows XP much more stable and reliable.

It depends on whether you want to do a job with your computer or spend your time tinkering with it.