# How to setup Canon InkJet Pixma IP 1300?

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, printing, canon, pixma

I am unable to setup Canon InkJet Pixma IP 1300 on Quantal AMD64. The things I have tried:

- Shut down and disconnect the printer before installing packages.
- Added the `ppa:michael-gruz/canon` repository to synaptic and installed the `cnijfilter-pixmaip1000series` package (there is no package for 1300 so I installed the nearest one). The PPA repository does not have packages for Quantal, so had to manually update the repository definition to "Oneiric" and refreshed it before downloading.
- Restarted cups via `sudo service cups restart`.
- Connected and switched on the printer.
- Opened All Settings -> Printers to Add a printer. There are 2 entries - One for the Standard USB Printer, another for "USB Printer - With Status Readback for Canon IJ" with Device URL as `cnijusb:/dev/usb/lp1`. Have selected this as per direction in [Ubuntu Community Forum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190?action=show&redirect=CanonCaptPrinterDriver).
- For manually entering a `.ppd` file I select `/usr/share/cups/model/cnpixmaip1000.ppd`.

  > ERROR MESSAGE : Failed to read PPD file.  Possible reason follows:
  >   /usr/share/cups/model/cnpixmaip1000.ppd: FAIL**FAIL**  Unable to open PPD file - No such file or directory on line 0.
- On checking I find that `cnpixmaip1000.ppd` file in `/usr/share/cups/model` is a symbolic link pointing to `/usr/share/ppd/cnpixmaip1000.ppd`.

However the later file does not exist. There are no other ppd files installed.

PS: Printing works fine with the shareware `TurboPrint for Linux`. So, there's nothing wrong with the printer.

Comment: This works for Canon PIXMA IP1300 on Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit

Answer (score 11):

Just installed the same printer on Quantal 32bit edition (canon pixma IP1300)....
These are the steps you should try:

1) Add repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-stable
```

2) Remove the printer installed in cups. And disconnect the printer.

3) `sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-ip2200series`

4) restart cups:

```
sudo service cups restart
```

5) chose printer ppd driver when installing the printer:

```
/usr/share/cups/model/canonip2200.ppd
```

6) print test page > succes.

Hope i helped you.

Comment: This works for Canon PIXMA IP1600 on Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: That repository is dead. No updates for recent Ubuntu, no stuff for 16.04 or later versions.

Answer (score 2):

August 2014 update:

The above answer (by hellyeah) worked for me for Canon PIXMA iP1600 (with 64 bit Ubuntu), with the exception that in step 1 I had to instead do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
sudo apt-get update
```

Hopefully this saves someone some time.

Answer (score 2):

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and these are what I did to install the printer:

- I followed the steps of @hellyeah's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240338/how-to-setup-canon-inkjet-pixma-ip-1300/260324#260324) but it failed at step 3.
- It worked only after trying the updated instruction of user 317642's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240338/how-to-setup-canon-inkjet-pixma-ip-1300/512547#512547)
- Finally, the Kohjah Breese's [tip](https://askubuntu.com/a/539770/279442) also helped a lot.

The summary of steps I did:

1. Add the repository

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk

   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. If you have any other installed attempt, remove the printer installed in CUPS.
3. Install the driver

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-ip2200series
   ```
4. Restart CUPS

   ```
   sudo service cups restart
   ```
5. To install the printer, go to administration settings.
6. Click on **Add Printer** button (with the printer ON and plugged in).
7. Select your printer from the local printers. Click **Continue** to proceed.
8. Where it says "Or Provide a PPD File, click Choose File", navigate to and select: `/usr/share/cups/model/canonip2200.ppd`
9. Print test page > success!

Comment: +1 for summarizing what you did to install the printer, based on existing answers.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just trying to help! By the way, @clearkimura You did great by editing the answer!

Comment: THIS WORKED FOR ME.. I was struggling for this for days.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stuck on stage 5, installing the printer means:

1. Go to `localhost:631`
2. Go to administration and enter your OS user and password.
3. Click on the *Add Printer* button (with the printer plugged in).
4. Select your printer from the local printers.
5. Press Continue.
6. Press Continue.
7. Where it says *Or Provide a PPD File*, click *Choose File* and navigate to and select: `/usr/share/cups/model/canonip2200.ppd`

Answer (score 0):

[Canon PIXMA iP1300 Printer Drivers](http://www.canonprintersdrivers.com/canon-pixma-ip1300-printer-drivers/)

It is safe to say that you’re looking for Printer drivers Canon PIXMA iP90 ? Just look at this page, you can download the drivers through the table through the tabs below for Windows 7,8,10 Vista and XP, Mac Os, Linux that you want. Here you can update your driver Canon and other drivers. canonprintersdrivers.com is a professional printer driver download site, it supplies all the drivers for the Canon printer drives.